# How to avoid 'docker stack deploy' command creating new volume

Tags: docker, amazon-efs

When I run the following command:

```sh
docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml mysql
```

It creates a new volume `mysql-test-efs-1`.  However, I want to use my existing EFS volume `test-efs-1`.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    volumes:
      - test-efs-1:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/my_file_secret
    secrets:
      - my_file_secret
secrets:
  my_file_secret:
    file: ./my_file_secret.txt
volumes:
  test-efs-1:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=fs-vvvv.efs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2
      device: fs-vvvv.efs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:/
```

Comment: How to solve this annoying problem?  thanks

Comment: Did you separately `docker volume create test-efs-1`, and you want to reuse that volume?  Or do you just see a `mysql-test-efs-1` volume in the `docker volume ls` listing?  Is the EFS content being used?  (Is the current directory named `mysql`?)

Comment: After I run the command-> docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml mysql.   it creates a new volume with driver local.  mysql-test-efs-1.

Comment: That seems normal, especially if the current directory is named `mysql`.  Compose includes its [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) in the names of most Docker objects it creates.

Comment: When I run docker volume inspect mysql-test-efs-1 it shows the data.   when I connect to my EFS,  cd ~/efs-test-point     >>> it shows exactly the same.  Does that mean it works properly???

Comment: That seems like it's working, yes.